# Weird cool screen in FF

Tags: firefox

I have no idea how i got to it. I do know it activates when I press Ctrl + Alt + Tab. However it only happens on a rare occasion. Here is a screencap:

[image]

Notice the X at the top right and the searchbar. Also note the loading... text. Do any of you know how to get to this screen?

Answer (score 1):

about:config (in the address bar, click through the warning) > set `browser.ctrlTab.previews` to true (double-click on the value). Double-click again to toggle it to false and disable the previews. The box from the screenshot appears to be Ctrl+Tab with previews enabled and then 
Show all X tabs (tab to the button or click it).

Search for `preview` in about:config for some related options.

Comment: Do you have any idea why sometimes it comes up and sometimes it doesnt (under the seemly default settings i am using now)?

Comment: Not I. Could you post your Firefox version and any related add-ons, though? That might help in the search.

Comment: 3.6. It doesnt matter tho since now i know what it is called. After a few days of it being on i'll decide if i always want or never want this feature.